# React Router isn't working ; Index Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I can't seem to solve this or find an answer. I have a basic `React Router` setup that I'm trying to get working and I'm really stuck on getting `IndexRoute` to it's linked component. I feel like I'm missing the point on how this `library` works and would love some advice.

Thanks in advance.

[Wireframe Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duhe2.png)

Here's the code.

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import reactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, hashHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import About from "./About Us/About"
import FrontPage from "./Front Page/FrontPage"
import HeaderNavigation from './General/HeaderNavigation';


reactDOM.render((
    <Router history = {hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={FrontPage}>
            <IndexRoute component = {HeaderNavigation}/>
            <Route path="/About" component={About}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

HeaderNavigation.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, MenuItem, NavItem, Link } from 'react-bootstrap';


export default React.createClass ({
    render() {
        var Dlink = 'https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12373357_497613000418878_5796459715901767943_n.png?oh=0484e476279b076d27eeeadc2d12b1d8&oe=590CD405'
        return (
            <Navbar>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <img src= {Dlink} alt="Legalink" height="6000 px"/>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                </Navbar.Header>
                    <Nav bsStyle = "pills">
                        <NavItem eventKey = "{1}" disabled>Product</NavItem>
                        <NavItem eventKey = "{2}">Support</NavItem>
                        <NavDropdown title  ="More" eventKey = "{3}">
                            <MenuItem eventKey = "{1}">Background</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem eventKey = "{2}">Contact Us</MenuItem>
                        </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
});
```

FrontPage.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Carousel from './Carousel';
import Body from './Body';

export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>
            <Carousel/>,
            <Body/>,
        </div>
    }
})
```

Body.js

```
import React from "react";

/* Styles */
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import Grid from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Grid';
import Jumbotron from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Jumbotron';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Col';
import typography from "../Assets/Typography"

export default React.createClass ( {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Jumbotron>
                    <Grid className = {typography}>
                        <h1>Tiger Jockey</h1>
                        <p>Bringing M&A to the Agile century</p>
                    </Grid>
                </Jumbotron>

                <Grid>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2 className = {typography}>Ride the Tiger</h2>
                            <p>Be the Jockey.</p>
                            <p><Button>View details »</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2>Please your Customer</h2>
                            <p>Win more work</p>
                            <p><Button>View details »</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2>Improve your process</h2>
                            <p>Make more money</p>
                            <p><Button>View details</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Carousel.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Carousel, CarouselItem, CarouselCaption, Image} from 'react-bootstrap';



export default React.createClass ( {
    render() {
        return (
            <Carousel>
                <CarouselItem>
                    <Image src = "https://d2myx53yhj7u4b.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/Temp_SimpleKanbanBoard_PPT.jpg" responsive/>
                    <div className ="Carousel-Caption">
                        <h3>Uno</h3>
                        <p>Duos</p>
                    </div>
                </CarouselItem>
                <CarouselItem>
                    <Image height = {702} width = {2028} src = "http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.1709251.1393876942!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/article_750/nup-148281-1237-jpg.jpg"/>
                    <div className ="Carousel-Caption">
                        <h3> Here we go</h3>
                        <p>Lawyered</p>
                    </div>
                </CarouselItem>
            </Carousel>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FrontPage.js` is the main page, and all other `component` you are passing as `child` component by `react-router`, so you need to specify the place where you want to `render` your `child` component in `FrontPage.js`, you forgot to add this line:

```
{this.props.children}
```

Try this:

```
import React from 'react';

import Carousel from './Carousel';
import Body from './Body';

export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return 
        <div>
            <Carousel/>
            <Body/>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    }
})
```

Comment: This solved my issue - but made me realise I had to move around the components.

How does {this.props.children} work? I am quite confused with this function and would love to expand my knowledge.

Comment: Really appreciate the help

Comment: in comments, not able to describe its meaning, it is like, your frontend is a home page or wrapper of all components, all other components will render inside it based on the route, it is a main comp and all other are its child comp, indexroute is default child.  read these: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: check this one too: https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/
mark the ans correct as it solved ur issue :)